# Grabbing first link in this code with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello this is the code I want to grab first link from using BeautifulSoup.

view-source:https://www.binance.com/en/blog

I want to grab the first article here so it would be "Trust Wallet Now Supports Stellar Lumens, 4 More Tokens"

I am trying to use Python for this.

I use this code but it grabs all the links, I only want first one to grab

```
with open('binanceblog1.html', 'w') as article:
    before13 = requests.get("https://www.binance.com/en/blog", headers=headers2)    
    data1b = before13.text

    xsoup2 = BeautifulSoup(data1b, "lxml")      
    for div in xsoup2.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'title sc-0 iaymVT'}):
        before_set13 = div.find('a')['href']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is wrong with the current code?

Comment: @balderman it grabs the last link from all the links in the findAll. it grabbed the argentina link (Binance Labs: BUIDLing Argentina’s Crypto Future) on the page

Comment: This is becuase you run in a loop over all divs...

Comment: @balderman yes so how would i grab the first link only?

Comment: Try to replace `findAll` with `find`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

    after_set13 = div.find('a')['href']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
None

Comment: `xsoup2.find(...)` not `div.find(..)`

Answer (score 0):

You can assess the situation inside the loop and `break` when you find a satisfactory result.

```
for div in xsoup2.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'title sc-62mpio-0 iIymVT'}):
    before_set13 = div.find('a')['href']
    if before_set13 != '/en/blog':
         break
    print('skipping ' + before_set13)
print('grab ' + before_set13)
```

Output of the code with these changes:

```
skipping /en/blog  
grab /en/blog/317619349105270784/Trust-Wallet-Now-Supports-Stellar-Lumens-4-More-Tokens
```

Comment: i dont think this would work since all the articles have /en/blog?

Comment: I am not testing whether it begins with `'/en/blog'`, I am testing whether it is the exact string. There is a link to `'/en/blog'` on the top of the page before the one you mentioned, that's why I used it as an example check.

Comment: I added output of the code with the proposed changes.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple solution I can think at this moment that works with your code is to use `break`, this is because of `findAll`

```
for div in xsoup2.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'title sc-62mpio-0 iIymVT'}):
    before_set13 = div.find('a')['href']
    break
```

For just the first element you can use `find`

`before_set13 = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'title sc-62mpio-0 iIymVT'}).find('a')['href']`

Answer (score 0):

Try (Extracting the href from 'Read more' button)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.binance.com/en/blog')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'read-btn sc-62mpio-0 iIymVT'})
print(div.find('a')['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the class name with class css selector (`.`) for the content section then `descendant combinator` with `a` type css selector to specify child `a` tag element. `select_one` returns first match

```
soup.select_one('.content a')['href']
```

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.binance.com/en/blog')   
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
link = soup.select_one('.content a')['href']
print('https://www.binance.com' + link)
```